# Extremely puzzling behavior when evaluating a tuple object that holds multiple DataFrames

Tags: python, if-statement, pandas, tuples, conditional-statements

I have some statements where I invoke a function that I defined myself:

```
sim_extracted_dfs = extract_dataframes(sim_queue_total_df_sim)
print (sim_extracted_dfs is tuple)
```

where `extract_dataframes()` is a function that accepts a large DataFrame as an argument and processes that DataFrame to return me a tuple consisting of 4 smaller DataFrames, as this is evident from the tuple that it returns to itself:

```
return ( pd.concat(objs = df_list_first_param, ignore_index = True),
       pd.concat(objs = df_list_second_param, ignore_index = True),
       pd.concat(objs = df_list_third_param, ignore_index = True),
       pd.concat(objs = df_list_fourth_param, ignore_index = True) )
```

As `sim_extracted_dfs` is a tuple object, I am going to use it later on in my codes in some `for` loops where I would iterate over each item (DataFrame in this case) of this tuple. However, I ran into some problems trying to do so, and I just realized that somehow, `sim_extracted_dfs` does not seem to be regarded as a tuple when I execute my codes non-interactively. With the following debugging statements:

```
print (sim_extracted_dfs is tuple)
print type(sim_extracted_dfs)
```

I get these very puzzling and contradictory corresponding outputs in Terminal upon executing `ipython data_analysis.py`, where data_analysis is the name of the module:

```
False
<type 'tuple'>
```

I went one step further to launch IPython and imported my module (the name of my module is data_analysis) so that I can do my debugging interactively, and this is what I got:

```
In [108]: type(data_analysis.sim_extracted_dfs)
Out[108]: tuple

In [109]: data_analysis.sim_extracted_dfs is tuple
Out[109]: True

In [110]: print (data_analysis.sim_extracted_dfs is tuple)
True

In [111]: print data_analysis.sim_extracted_dfs is tuple
True

In [112]:
```

This is really driving me nuts. Is this a bug or something? Why is it that now `sim_extracted_dfs is tuple` is `True`? I've been stuck at just this one problem for almost the entire day now and I can't move forward with the rest of my module because everything else depends on this conditional to evaluate my tuple of DataFrames correctly. I will really appreciate any help on this.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Well, consider using `isinstance(sim_extracted_dfs, tuple)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use the `is` operator for comparing types. From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#not-in):

> The operators `is` and `is not` test for object identity: `x is y` is true if and only if `x` and `y` are the same object.

Instead, try using [`isinstance`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#isinstance):

```
isinstance(sim_extracted_dfs, tuple)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. It works right now. However, do you have any idea why `is` behaved the way it did? Although I used it wrongly, I'd like to know why it broke down so badly the way it did...

Comment: @AKKO `x is tuple` tests if the object x is *the class object* tuple - ie, if you've done `x = tuple` (or something equivalent). It doesn't test whether x is *a* tuple.

Comment: Hmmm it did not work when I did it because `sim_extracted_dfs` is actually an instance of the tuple class, is that the case? But why did I get contradictory results from this test between the non-interactive and interactive execution of this statement?

Comment: @AKKO I think `x is y` is essentially the same as [`id(x) == id(y)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#id). I'm not sure why you would get those results. Maybe IPython (or your code) overwrites `tuple` to something else?

Comment: @grc beats me man. I didn't have any statements overwriting the data type so it doesn't make sense why I get two different behaviors. That's why I said this whole thing was driving me nuts...